# How to format code in Android Studio (IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: android-studio, code-formatting

I want to format code in a freshly created Android application.

I messed up the code in this manner:

```
 private static final
    int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS
            = 3000;
```

I want to format it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, but it is not repairing the code. I use Windows 8.1.

Comment: When you press `ctrl+alt+l` do you get a reformat prompt? just to make sure that something else is not reacting to this shortcut. sometimes it helps to highlight the code first.

Comment: `ctrl+alt+l` works fine with me. I'm currently using windows 8.1 too.

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+L` or `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L` for dialog

Comment: But [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) is not the same as [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA)(?). Two different [IDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)(?). Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 54):

Just right-click on the project or directory, and select **Reformat Code**
[image: Reformat Code]

Comment: A nice way to do it for multiple files at once, thanks.

Comment: make sure you check rearrange entries if you want same results as "Order/FormatCode" i.e. ctrl+alt+L

Answer (score 42):

If you want to:

1. Order/FormatCode: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
2. Implement Methods: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
3. Override Methods: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

There isn't any need for them to be capital letters. This is just for the example.

Comment: its not working for android studio 2.2. Please update answer

Answer (score 38):

First you will need to configure how your code is formatted. This can be done by going to

`[Main Menu]` -> `File` -> `Settings`
then go to
`(Project Settings)` -> `Code Style` -> `Java`

In this area you can define all the formatting rules that you would like to apply to your code.

Now you should check (or change) the keyboard shortcut for reformatting code by going to

`[Main Menu]` -> `File` -> `Settings`
then go to
 `(IDE Settings)` -> `Keymap`

Just type `Reformat Code` into the search box at the top right to find it.

Once this is done, highlight the code you want to reformat and use the keyboard shortcut to reformat your code based on the rules you defined.

Comment: For some reason it still doesnt work for me. I want to use the automatic formatting to remove the double spaced lines in the code snippets i copy to the Editor. The code formatting refuses to do that for me.

Comment: Somewhere is a setting that is something along the lines of "format after pasting" (I'm unsure of the exact wording right now) which should be enabled. If that still does not work, then perhaps your rules aren't setup correctly to remove double spaced lines - I'm not sure that there are any rules to remove single line spaces (only two empty lines).

Comment: @free3dom Is there any way to do this with bash script? Reformat code from a bash script? Or run a shortcut command from bash script?

Answer (score 12):

In Android Studio (on the Mac), I select the code chunk, and then select the *Code* menu item and click *Auto-Indent Lines*.

**See screenshot:**

[image]

Shortcut key (on Mac) is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

Answer (score 6):

At least on my Android Studio version, "keep when formatting - line breaks" was enabled by default. So you need to go to

*Preferences* → *Editor* → *Code Style* → *Java* and disable that checkbox (see the below screenshot).

[image: Android Studio Preferences]

Comment: Where is *"Preferences"*? Is it a menu?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> is the shortcut key for arranging the code in Ubuntu (Android Studio).