# How do i make android studio code not one line

Tags: android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuE02.png)

The thing is that I don't wanna make it long I want to make it short and have a break. I don't really know what I did to make it this way. By default when I copy and paste a code it would have breaks but now when I do it it will become one long line of words which makes it very unsightly. How do I make it have an auto break and not manually do it??

Answer (score 0):

There is a shortcut called **Format Code**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411280/how-to-format-code-in-android-studio-intellij).